# Not including stdlib.h?

Tags: c

Been reading through a lot of the bigger, more popular threads here on SO and found the thread about casting malloc() returns particularly interesting. I'm guilty of casting my returns simply because this is how I was taught.

The thing I'm wondering is, if casting a return from `malloc()` can hide bugs from not including `stdlib.h` then why is the answer not to cast rather than to always make sure `stdlib.h` is included?

Isn't not including `stdlib.h` lazy or bad practice or am I missing something? I realise there are other reasons for not casting but this one stands out for me in particular since it seems like bad practice is in some small way being promoted or accepted here.

So are there any particular instances where one would willingly not include `stdlib.h` if it's actually required? I see a lot of people being put down for doing these things... casting, yet it seems that nobody really has a problem with this negligence... can someone explain why casting the return is frowned on yet neglecting to include necessary headers is not?

I know it's a contentious issue here and has been the subject of various threads in the past. I'm trying to get back up to speed with things here and break old habits.

Lastly, any good sources of info that's more up to date with current standards...I'm still finding various examples online where the casting is being done, and some of them are quite recent.

A lot of conflicting info out there. Why would you not want to include `stdlib.h` or be so cavalier with regards to that, yet be so pedantic about the casting?

Comment: You can be a C programmer and have a life. There are a few specimens in captivity. They tend to not be the most hygienic creatures :-)

Comment: That's like saying “If this prevents you from accidentally shooting yourself in the foot, why don't you make sure to never shoot yourself in the foot instead?”

Comment: Sorry, don't want to go into too much personal details, I have mny reasons and it's not particularly relevant. I apologise for providing simple background info.

Comment: When I accidentally use `malloc` without including `stslib.h`, clang warns me. And it's always better to get rid of the warnings and do what the compiler tells you to do.

Comment: No need to apologise. It's best to keep in mind that SO is about Q/A styled communication, rather than a forum.

Comment: No probs, just hoping to clean up my act a bit and appreciate the input.

Comment: Not casting the return value *reveals* that `stdlib.h` is missing, of course you're expected to include it afterwards.

Comment: There's an abundance of examples and tuts out there teaching the use of malloc the casting way. Old habits die hard, I guess. I'm a living example of this. Think I need to do some proper revision - much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "strong-typing" idea says that the compiler should be able to catch most of the programmer's errors before the program is run. Not doing the proper `#include` is an error, which the compiler can catch (unless you inadvertently suppress it by casting).

"Don't do this error" is not a solution - bugs always happen.

This sort of error is plausible, because it's annoying to check whether your code already has the proper `#include` whenever you add dynamic memory allocations to it. People tend to forget (or "forget") to do annoying things.

Answer (score 2):

Especially in situations like this:

```
void addSomeData(someType **data) {
     ...
     ... manylines ...

     data = (someType *) malloc(sizeof(someType)*n);
```

where it should have been:

```
     *data = (someType *) malloc(sizeof(someType)*n);
```

Here the cast enables the compiler to check if you did really what you intended to do. Furthermore, adding redundant information to code can enhance or worsen readability, it is a matter of the situation, the code writers *and* code readers personal style.

On the other hand, in code lines like this:

```
struct foo *bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
```

a cast probably indeed would be of no benefit.

However, I think it is a too simple and indifferentiate rule to say, that a cast of `malloc()` is always an error (!), as a much cited answer here on SO claims.